# When using ServiceStack templates, is it possible to shape output of htmldump with attributes on dumped object?

Tags: servicestack

The code below will output a html table with the values "Name" and "Age" in the first column. Is it possible to output something else like "Navn" for "Name" and "Alder" for "Age"? If so, how? I've tried adding attributes like [DisplayName] and [DataMember] on the properties of the Person class without any success.

```
using (var context = new TemplateContext().Init())
{
    context.VirtualFiles.WriteFile("page.html", "{{person | htmldump}}");
    var pageResult = new PageResult(context.GetPage("page"))
    {
        Args = {["person"] = new Person{Age = "20", Name = "Ada"}}
    };
    var htmlString = await pageResult.RenderToStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(htmlString);
}

public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack Templates [HTML Filters](http://templates.servicestack.net/) just renders the property name of each item, so to change the Property Names it uses you can just select a new Object using the `map` filter with the property names you want, e.g:

```
{{ people | map => { Navn:it.Name, Alder:it.Age } | htmlDump }}
```